# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')` error and I couldn't find why. Here is my `index.js` and `User.js` files in `models` folder;

index.js;

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const config = require('../../config/database.js');

const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.hostname] = model;
    db[model.username] = model;
    db[model.password] = model;
    db[model.command] = model;
    db[model.status] = model;
    db[model.cpu] = model;
    db[model.mac] = model;
    db[model.info] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

User.js;

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    /* id : DataTypes.INTEGER, */
    hostname: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    command: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.STRING,
    cpu: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    mac: DataTypes.STRING,
    info: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

And here is my controller `UserController.js` file ;

```
const { User } = require('../models');

module.exports = {

    index(req, res) {
        User.findAll({})
            .then(users => res.json({
                error: false,
                data: users
            }))
            .catch(error => res.json({
                error:true,
                data: [],
                error: error
            }));
    },

    create(req, res) {
        const { /* id, */hostname,username,password,command,status,cpu,mac,info} = req.body;
        User.create({
            /* id, */hostname,username,password,command,status,cpu,mac,info
        })
        .then(user => res.status(201).json({
            error: false,
            data: user,
            message: "new user has been created"
        }))
        .catch(error => res.json({
            error:true,
            data: [],
            error: error
        }));
    },

    update(req, res) {
        const user_id = req.params.id;

        const { hostname,username,password,command,status,cpu,mac,info } = req.body;

        User.update({
            hostname,username,password,command,status,cpu,mac,info
        }, {
            where: {
                id: user_id
            }
        })
        .then(user => res.status(201).json({
            error: false,
            data: user,
            message: 'user has been updated'
        }))
        .catch(error => res.json({
            error: true,
            error: error
        }));
    },

    destroy(req, res) {
        const user_id = req.params.id;

        User.destroy({ where: {
            id: user_id
        }})
        .then(status => res.status(201).json({
            error: false,
            message: 'user has been deleted'
        }))
        .catch(error => res.json({
            error: true,
            error: error
        }));
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out what caused this problem. I'd be glad if you could help.Here is my project directory ;

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeGE8.png)

Comment: Looks like you've missed to sync your models with database with `sequelize.sync()`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an empty object to `User.findAll({})` in your `UserController.js` file.

Try `User.findAll()`, instead.

Comment: @Didem, was this helpful? Were you able to make any progress on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just last night, and it was happening to me because I was calling `findAll()` before I synced sequelize `sequelize.sync()`. That is why it is returning undefined. Not sure if it happening to you for the same reason because you haven't attached the code for your server.js. Also either pass in an attribute prop inside the `findAll({})` or get rid of the curly braces.